# loop thru folders using linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to loop though directories and show the files on a webpage.
I have managed to find a script, but it doesnt do the loop
any advice? At the moment I can only view whats on the current folder

thanks in advance
Hesh

Controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {


        DirectoryInfo assetsDirectory = null;
        FileInfo[] files = null;

            //string salesFTPPath = dirPath;
            assetsDirectory = new DirectoryInfo( Server.MapPath("~/assets/img"));
            files = assetsDirectory.GetFiles();
            Response.Write(assetsDirectory);

        var MaterialFiles = (from c in files 
                          select c);

        return View(MaterialFiles);

    }
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<FileInfo>

 @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
              @item.DirectoryName - @item.Name.ToString() 
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean it should be recursive?

Comment: Hi 
Sorry yes
for example
folder 1
  file 1, file 2
  subfolder file 1, file 2
folder 2
   etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ:

```
FileList.Select(f => f.FullName).ToArray();
```

Alternatively, using Directory you can get filenames directly.

```
string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(DirPath, "*.*", 
                                       SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: Many thanks for this
with the LINQ how do I define the start directory?

 var MaterialFiles = files.Select(f => f.FullName).ToArray();
 return View(MaterialFiles);

Comment: ok you need to find sub directories first. Please follow the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx.